# Can someone explain Couple with respect to forces acting on it?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation, equilibrium

[image]

Suppose two inequal, parallel and opposite forces $P$ and $Q$ are acting on a body not along the same line, producing a clockwise moment. If the rod on which its acting is massless, then we can extend the rod beyond the point where $Q$ is being applied and we can place a pivot at the point where the net force $F_{net}=Q-P$ is acting, such that the pivot applies an equal and opposite reaction force $F_r$ at the same point, and the body is at static equilibrium.

[image]

Hoping that my assumptions are correct till now,

How can we explain a couple in terms of force? If both the forces are equal and opposite, then the net force turns out to be $0$, so is it in dynamic equilibrium? But does it mean we can never "Stop" a couple from acting by using a pivot, just like we did it here? In other words, **Can someone explain the logic behind couples with respect to forces acting on it?**